# GAE - Flask - OSError: [Errno 13] path not accessible:

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I am trying since 2 days to get flask running, but with all templates i get the same error messages

I am using Windows 7 64bit

https://github.com/kamalgill/flask-appengine-template/

OOSError: [Errno 13] path not accessible: 'c:\python27\dlls'

from pkq_resources , function : find_on_path

So I thought maybe it's a windows thing so I deployed it to my GAE app and it worked.

http://kanta3d.appspot.com

But i don't want to deploy it every time, this would kill the workflow.

I googled this error but I could not find a fix.

I did some investigation and this function in pkq_resources throws the error

```
for entry in os.listdir(path_item): # this throws the error
```

.

```
def find_on_path(importer, path_item, only=False):
    """Yield distributions accessible on a sys.path directory"""
    path_item = _normalize_cached(path_item)

    if os.path.isdir(path_item) and os.access(path_item, os.R_OK):
        if path_item.lower().endswith('.egg'):
            # unpacked egg
            yield Distribution.from_filename(
                path_item, metadata=PathMetadata(
                    path_item, os.path.join(path_item,'EGG-INFO')
                )
            )
        else:
            # scan for .egg and .egg-info in directory
            for entry in os.listdir(path_item):
                lower = entry.lower()
                if lower.endswith('.egg-info'):
                    fullpath = os.path.join(path_item, entry)
                    if os.path.isdir(fullpath):
                        # egg-info directory, allow getting metadata
                        metadata = PathMetadata(path_item, fullpath)
                    else:
                        metadata = FileMetadata(fullpath)
                    yield Distribution.from_location(
                        path_item,entry,metadata,precedence=DEVELOP_DIST
                    )
                elif not only and lower.endswith('.egg'):
                    for dist in find_distributions(os.path.join(path_item, entry)):
                        yield dist
                elif not only and lower.endswith('.egg-link'):
                    for line in open(os.path.join(path_item, entry)):
                        if not line.strip(): continue
                        for item in find_distributions(os.path.join(path_item,line.rstrip())):
                            yield item
                        break
```

full source at :

https://github.com/kamalgill/flask-appengine-template/blob/master/src/pkg_resources.py

Comment: I have the same issue. On Debian it works but not on Windows.

Comment: Does that directory actually exist?

Answer (score 0):

I think taking ownership of the folder in question should work. I had the same issue on Windows 10 and I had to do this on powershell to overcome this problem.

.\takeown.exe /f "C:\users\" /r /d y